# How can I use vector graphics (defined in XAML) as the image of a Ribbon menu item?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon, vector-graphics

I need to convert my WPF application, which has a `Ribbon`, to use vector graphics for the images on buttons, etc., instead of bitmaps. I've got this working so far, except for the `RibbonApplicationMenu` items, which use their `RibbonApplicationMenu.ImageSource` property, with type `ImageSource` to set the graphic that shows up at the left side of the ribbon menu item.

My vector graphics are defined like this in `XAML`:

```
<ControlTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ViewBox Width="148.854" Height="150.500">
        <Canvas Width="148.854" Height="150.500">
            <Path>
            <!-- . . . yadda yadda yadda . . . -->
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    <Viewbox>
</ControlTemplate>
```

These render properly when I set them to be the `.Template` of a `Button`, etc.

I can't figure out, however, how to use them for the images that show up in the `RibbonApplicationMenu` controls. Just setting the `.Template` property of the `RibbonApplicationMenu` does not work (it fills the entire control seems to break its functionality).

I attempted to use a `VisualBrush` and then render it to a `RenderTargetBitmap` to use as the `.ImageSource` (I also have to work mostly in code behind for reasons I won't get into):

```
ContentControl cc = new ContentControl(); // just picked ContentControl as a test
cc.Template = myTemplate; // assume myTemplate has the proper ControlTemplate
VisualBrush visBrush = new VisualBrush();
visBrush.Visual = cc;
// not really sure about the parameters to this next line 
RenderTargetBitmap rend = 
    new RenderTargetBitmap(148.854, 150.5, 120, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
rend.Render(cc);
RibbonApplicationMenuItem menu = new RibbonApplicationMenuItem();
menu.ImageSource = render;
```

This compiles, but just shows a blank where the image would go. If I instead use a `BitmapImage` loaded from an image file as the `.ImageSource`, it displays correctly.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that might need to be done:
Firstly there is no explicit size set for the `Canvas` in the `ControlTemplate`, you'll need to    assign it a width and height (see [the upvoted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332956/putting-canvas-inside-viewbox-in-silverlight-with-image) for details).
The other thing is that you need to `Arrange` and `Measure` the `Viewbox` so that it assumes the required dimensions.

So altering the xaml for the vector graphics to something like:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Template">
    <Viewbox>
        <Canvas Height="100" Width="130">
            <Path>
                <!-- data -->
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And the code to:

```
ControlTemplate controlTemplate = 
    FindResource("Template") as ControlTemplate; 

ContentControl content = new ContentControl();
content.Template = controlTemplate;

// ensure control has dimensions
content.Measure(new Size(200, 200));
content.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200));

RenderTargetBitmap render =
    new RenderTargetBitmap((int)content.ActualWidth, (int)content.ActualHeight, 120, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

render.Render(content);

RibbonApplicationMenuItem menu = new RibbonApplicationMenuItem();
menu.ImageSource = render;
```

Will hopefully get it working.

Comment: Sorry I should have included more detail in my code above. I do have a size set for the canvas (and I edited in those attributes in my question). I will try Measure and Arrange asap.

Comment: Using `.Measure` and `.Arrange` got the thing to show up in the Ribbon. I'm not sure if it's exactly what I need, but it worked. It's not lined up properly, though, but I can probably fiddle with it.